# Failed to create a session; confirm that the user has the proper privileges to log on to Microsoft Dynamics

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I started Dynamics AX 2012, I try to compare classes before importing them and I get this error:

> Failed to create a session; confirm that the user has the proper privileges to log on to Microsoft Dynamics.

Could someone tell me what could be the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of 3 options:

1. Restart the AOS
2. Do an incremental CIL compile
3. Do a full CIL compile

Please report back which of them resolved your problem.

[Others](http://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33/t/48661.aspx) have had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

“..confirm that the user has the proper privileges..”

Check if the AX AOS service account has the appropriate database roles (reader, writer, admin) assigned to the model and data database, is an ax user and has access to the application folder.

Reviewing the authorization settings for the AX service account solved this issue in my case.